# switch with scanf one more input

Tags: c

I'd like to ask, if somebody can help me with the problem I have in my code. I mean while I want scanf  2 variables, code want one more input.. dunno whats wrong.. 
btw: I add part of the code

[image]

```
for(i;i<4;i++){
    switch(i){
    case 0:{
        printf("Bod #1:\n");
        scanf("%d%d\n",&x1,&y1);
        printf("x1=%d y1=%d\n",x1,y1);
        printf("working 1\n");
    }
    break;
```

Comment: `scanf("%d%d\n",&x1,&y1);` --> `scanf("%d%d%*c",&x1,&y1);` or `scanf("%d%d",&x1,&y1);` ... it waits for input until there is a non-blank character when there is `\n`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'd definitely make that an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt think that \n would make that bug, because in next cases it didnt make same mistake as at case 0. One more time Big thx and hug from me ! ^_^

Comment: Always check the return value of input functions (`scanf` in your case).

Comment: Next time I´m going to be more careful...
btw: Is it just low reputation or what that i cannot find mark a question answerd?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with this line:

```
scanf ("%d%d\n", &x1, &y1);
```

specifically the `\n` in the format string. Referencing the standard (`C11 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /5` and keeping in mind that `\n` is a white-space character:

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input **up to the first non-white-space character** (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.

So, as per the input values in your question, `scanf` starts processing the format string `"%d%d\n"`.

The first format specifier `%d` needs more input and, when you enter `45\n`, it skips any white-space (of which there is none) and loads the integer into its variable, leaving `x1 == 45` and the input stream thus (`^` represents the next read point):

```
45\n
  ^
```

The second format specifier `%d` skips white-space (the `\n`) and then needs more data so you enter `459\n`. It then loads that integer into its variable, leaving `y1 == 459` and the input stream thus:

```
45\n459\n
       ^
```

Here's where your problem starts. The *final* format specifier `\n` needs to read up to *but not including* the first non-white-space character. But it cannot *tell* that there's a non-white-space character at this point (since you may enter some more white-space), so it again needs more input which you provide: `54\n`. This leaves the input stream as:

```
45\n459\n54\n
       ^
```

So now, the `\n` format specifier knows that the `5` in `54` is the first non-white-space character and it stops before reading that, giving:

```
45\n459\n54\n
         ^
```

*That's* the point at which `scanf()` returns since all format specifiers have been satisfied. Of course, the next call to `scanf("%d%d...")` will already have `54\n` in the input stream so that will be used to populate `x1`. You'll *still* have to enter two more values before `scanf()` returns, the first which will populate `y1` and the second which will satisfy the `\n` specifier.

---

Now, how to fix it. Well, that's pretty easy. As alluded to above, `%d` (and most other format strings) skip white-space before they attempt to read their data.

That means newlines will be automatically ignored if you just use `"%d%d"` as your format string, *without* the problmatic `\n`.

See, for example the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int x1, y1;

    printf("Bod #1:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x1,&y1);
    printf("x1=%d y1=%d\n",x1,y1);
    printf("working 1\n");

    printf("\nBod #2:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x1,&y1);
    printf("x1=%d y1=%d\n",x1,y1);
    printf("working 2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and sample run:

```
Bod #1:
45
459
x1=45 y1=459
working 1

Bod #2:
314159
271828
x1=314159 y1=271828
working 2
```